# mura 6.2 dspinclude not working when not set up with site-ids

Tags: mura

When I set up my Mura, I selected the option to not use site-ids, which I think is the root of this problem. When I try it on another Mura installation, which uses site-ids, it works fine.

Here is the code for the include:

```
[mura]$.dspinclude('display_objects/custom/cfchart/inc_chart_form.cfm')[/mura]
```

The error is:

> GET  http://sellyastuff/mura-6.2.6526/index.cfm/cfchart/ [HTTP/1.1 404
>   Content Not Found 509ms]

Edit: Note that this is a multi-site setup and I am applying this include to one of these sites.

The actual server physical path on my local dev machine is:

> http://sellyastuff/mura-6.2.6526/just-jeans/includes/display_objects/custom/cfchart/inc_chart_form.cfm

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your error is actually being caused by something in the `inc_chart_form.cfm` file. Maybe put a `<h1>Hello from inc_chart_form.cfm</h1><cfabort />` at the top of the file, and try it again.

Also, this could be an issue with your rewrite rules ... so, you may want to disable those and try again if the first suggestion doesn't work.